# Asynchronous timer in Linux

Tags: linux, asynchronous

I want to use an asynchronous timer which fires a call back function when it expires. I want the precison in micro secs.
my code flow goes like this..

```
timer_t tid;
struct itimerspec val;

val.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
val.it_value.tv_nsec = 100000;

value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 100000;

timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &tid);
timer_connect (tid, myfunc,0);
timer_settime (tid, 0, &val, NULL);



and write my handle function:

myfunc(){
blah blah blah...
}
```

I think timer_connect is not been used in recent Linux versions.. Do I have an alternative?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Indeed timer_connect does not exist in recent Linux version. Actually, I'm quite sure it doesn't exist in ANY Linux version, recent or not. Some googling suggests it's something found in VxWorks. It's not found in POSIX either, FWIW.

In Linux (and POSIX) you can provide a pointer to a struct sigevent as the second argument to timer_create() (the one which is NULL in your example). struct sigevent in turn has a member (*sigev_notify_function) which, as the name implies, is the function to call when the timer expires (this requires that the notification method is SIGEV_THREAD).

Comment: I was trying the same and mean while thought if I have any alternative.. Thanks a lot for the info @Janneb. Will try this and get back to  you

Comment: IS there any otherway of implementing ayncronous timer without using signals?

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't use SIGEV_SIGNAL as the notification method, or leave the *evp argument to timer_create as NULL.

Comment: How do I get notified? you mean I can register any handler there? can you give me a reference code?

Comment: Use SIGEV_THREAD and provide a function pointer to call if you don't want to use a signal. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: Thanks.. it works.

If I have to verify if the handler function invoked in exact time as set.. how do I verify? I want to check in nanosec resolution.